# Appcelerator iOS Module

Tags: ios, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

I am creating a module for the card reader where they have used `NSRunLoop`. The NSRunLoop is not being called and I am stuck in the middle of no mans land. Basically the following line of code is not being executed while running on the device.

```
NSRunLoop *theRL = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
NSDate *loopUntil = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1;                           
while (dialogOpen == TRUE && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:loopUntil]){
    NSLog(@"While Loop");
}
```

Can this be achieved via the Appcelerator so that I can substitute the above objective-C code with the appcelerator code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put an NSLog with numbers after each line and see where it gets stuck.

Do you have any errors or app crash?

did you check that the while condition evals to true?